# Laravel 5 bearer token authentication

Tags: laravel-5, bearer-token

How do I get the bearer token that I passed from Postman in a Laravel 5 controller? I am executing the following code:

```php
$request = request(); 
$token = $request->bearerToken();
echo $token;
```

Nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by debugging the headers as they are sent, so simply try:

```php
dd($request->headers);
```

Now you can view all headers as they are received by your controller.

Then check for the `Authorization` header, which should contain some value like: `Bearer 123abc456def`. This `Bearer`  prefix is required (you should , and the Laravel code will look for this, such that `$request->bearerToken()` only returns `123abc456def`.

Note that this `Bearer`  prefix is case-senstive, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-1.1:

> Unless otherwise noted, all the protocol parameter names and values
> are case sensitive.

Comment: when i put this code, dd($request->headers);  it returns header details as below and there is no bearer token found

Comment: HeaderBag {#48
  #headers: array:8 [
    "content-length" => array:1 [
      0 => "398"
    ]
    "content-type" => array:1 [
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "accept" => array:1 [
      0 => "*/*"
    ]
    "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
      0 => "gzip, deflate, br"
    ]
    "connection" => array:1 [
      0 => "keep-alive"
    ]
    "host" => array:1 [
      0 => "adoxapp.com"
    ]
    "postman-token" => array:1 [
      0 => "320278a0-5717-497d-9693-f3b40d4a43e2"

Comment: Then it appears that you are not sending that header (correctly) in Postman? Thats a pretty obvious conclusion :)

Comment: issue fixed  ..  it was missing the below code in .htaccess file# Handle Authorization Header
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]